# application context information sometimes not available in g:link

Tags: tomcat, grails

Our application is installed on numerous systems:  there are developer boxes,  development integration systems,  QA systems, staging systems, a demo system and production systems.   For several months now, we have been plagued by any of these systems losing the application context in their URL. For example, instead of `qasys1.company.com/appName/dashboard`  the URL is formed as `qasys1.company.com/dashboard` which results in a 404.

The `appName` just stops showing up in the URLs.  It isn't related to specific code changes because the same application version can show the problem on one system and not another.  It doesn't seem to be tied to specific systems. I believe they have all exhibited the problem at one time or another.

Here is what I know, any suggestions for where to go looking or what the problem could be would be much appreciated:

The problem happens within the `g:link` tag. Sometimes it includes the application context and sometimes not.

The problem seems to happen on application start up. Sometimes the system will start up and the app context will be shown, sometimes not.

For all of these systems, we use tomcat 7 with the following definition in server.xml:

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"
unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

We do define `grails.app.context` in our config file, which doesn't seem to resolve the issue. I've read that `grails.app.context` is really only used on the developer systems with an embedded tomcat. So the lack of any effect would make sense for us:  All of these systems are set up in the production environment.

We do not define `grails.serverUrl` because of issues with Spring.  However, I've read that `grails.serverUrl` is only needed for redirects and we are not having problems with our redirects.

We are using grails 2.2.4

We do get different effects with different browsers. For example, the URLs may be lacking the application context if we use Firefox, but not if the request is issued in Chrome. (But there isn't enough consistency in this happening to say that it is a particular browser or browser version.)

Comment: I think a good start to solving this is to determine whether the problem is within Grails or Tomcat. Any easy way to do this is to use a different servlet container, perhaps a simpler one like Jetty Runner: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/runner.html You can run the app with a specific context path like this: `java -jar jetty-runner.jar --port 8080 --path /appName someApp.war`